# Understanding Youtube HTML5 Query String

Tags: html, youtube

I've been doing some research into Youtube's new HTML 5 player and DASH implementation. I'm starting work with Wireshark and utilities like DummyNet to see how the bitrate reacts with changes in bandwidth. But before I can get into this I need to better understand the packets I'm seeing. I'm mainly looking for help decoding the GET requests. I have been filtering my Wireshark captures by 'http.request.method == GET' and following the TCP streams. I see that the parameters are: clen, dur, gcr, gir, id, ip, ipbits, itag, lmt, source, upn, expire. Some are straightforward others are not. I am most confused about clen, upn, lmt, and a param labeled mt which is not listed as a sparam. I am most interested in finding the bitrate requested. But am now confused as to whether I'm looking in the right place. clen is the only field which could be seen as a value in Mbps. But the value often doesn't comply with what youtube lists as possible bitrates for certain qualities. They are also seemingly odd values for bitrates. Here is a sample request URL:

```
http://r15---sn-p5qlsney.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?lmt=1389519273541060&source=youtube&expire=1394008508&sver=3&dur=191.692&itag=243&upn=dPjd90tRg4o&id=o-ANPasmTb-Kbiei84oPQpCjzKQT9ypEOEBqSpq3YmfDmZ&fexp=906373%2C931942%2C934913%2C916612%2C937417%2C937416%2C913434%2C936910%2C936913%2C902907%2C934022%2C3300021%2C3300114%2C3300131%2C3300137%2C3300164%2C3310366%2C3310628%2C3310649&gir=yes&signature=898DF292EE99A453258333B40880CC72BCE453D1.DB976A3B1EB55CF43C36F6FFF2AF329FAD2E9EE4&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&ipbits=0&ip=128.226.230.194&key=yt5&clen=4951576&cpn=BzQtGIscpjryZJ1D&alr=yes&mime=video%2Fwebm&ratebypass=yes&redirect_counter=1&cms_redirect=yes&ms=nxu&mt=1393986619&mv=m&range=1737754-2707644&keepalive=yes
```

I am using Google Chrome as a browser and making sure that all videos I inspect are using the HTML5 player with DASH active.

Comment: I have been looking more into DASH and have found out that an initialization segment will sometimes be sent separately from the media segments. There seem to be periodic requests for files which may be initialization segments. If someone could confirm their use of this it would be useful.

Comment: `clen` is the size of the file in bytes